# Word VBA - Matching large selecting of text based keys with data. Embedded resource/text?

Tags: vba, ms-word, hashmap, embed, embedded-resource

I have a pretty complex VBA plugin for Word written that automatically creates a report for me, using XML input, cycling through the X objects within the report to create the output. It is currently embedded into a Word Template file .DOCM.

I need to insert into the report a static list of text, based on the name of the item within the XML. For example, within my XML I have entries with a name BLAH1, BLAH2, BLAH3. Every time I see BLAH1, I need to match it with the static INSERT1, and BLAH2 match it with INSERT2, etc.

This seems simple enough, but her lies the problem...

It appears there are no Hashmap's in VBA without requiring external libraries, which I can't really rely on, since I can't install items on the machines where this will be running. As a result I can't store this reference data in a Hashmap as far as I can tell.

I can't seem to concatenate more than about 20 lines of strings together without hitting a max within VBA, and just parsing the chunk of text for what I need since there are about 1500 "lines" in my reference data, which greatly exceeds 20.

I also haven't found a way to embed a text, or any other type of file to hold this information within the file, and then parse the data.

I really would like to have everything within the single template file, without requiring additional text or other files to be bundled with the document. If there is no other option, I will go that route, but I wanted to see what create ideas people at Stackoverflow might have first ;-)

Comment: What "max" are you talking about?? Strings in VBA can be up to 2 billion characters long. Also, VBA has two hash types: `Collection` and `Dictionary`. `Collection`s can use string keys, while `Dictionary`s can use object references and all types of scalar values as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Word's Document Variables? They are name/value pairs stored invisibly within the document. (ActiveDocument.Variables("BLAH1").Value = "INSERT1" to create one, debug.print ActiveDocument.Variables("BLAH1").Value to retrieve a value (you have to use an error handler to detect non-existent indices if you go that route). Word can store (at least) hundreds of thousands of these things).